# The suggestion window will not turn off

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to turn off this suggestion window because it doesn't help.
[image]

I have ticked off 'Automatically trigger code completions' at 'Settings>editor', but the window still pops up. What can I do to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of it by setting the 'Code Diagnostics' option to 'None' in the Settings->editor window.

[image]